# Variables in Chef guard interpreter

Tags: powershell, chef-infra, guard, recipe

Is variable evaluation possible with the chef `guard_interpreter` resource?  It does not work in this code.  Thanks!

```
guard_interpreter :powershell_script  
not_if '( (gwmi win32_computersystem).name -eq "#{servername}" )'
```

Comment: Figured out the problem.  I needed double quotes, not single around the powershell code:  not_if "( (gwmi win32_computersystem).name -eq "#{servername}" )"

Comment: Yep, that's exactly the problem :). You should answer your own question :)